# How to get a Symfony Embedded Dynamic Form Unmapped data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a dynamic form that is generated dynamically like the following.

```
<input type="hidden" id="project_teams_18_cropped_file_key" name="project[teams][1][cropped_file_key]" class="cropped_file_key">
<input type="hidden" id="project_teams_18_cropped_file_key" name="project[teams][2][cropped_file_key]" class="cropped_file_key">
<input type="hidden" id="project_teams_18_cropped_file_key" name="project[teams][8][cropped_file_key]" class="cropped_file_key">
.....
<input type="hidden" id="project_teams_18_cropped_file_key" name="project[teams][dynamic_key][cropped_file_key]" class="cropped_file_key">
```

Form Type:

```
->add('cropped_file_key', HiddenType::class, [
    'mapped' => false
])
```

Since the form inputs key are in random order I cannot do
`foreach($project->getTeams() as $key => $value){}` because $key runs in a sequence mannerr.

I tried like `$form->get('cropped_file_key')` it didn't work and it asks for the key.
What is the best way to get the value of such dynamic form inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Is your FormType is your parent form or is it a child form with type of CollectionType ?

If it is a child form, as mentonned in this post [Access Embedded Form Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686720/access-embedded-form-data-symfony), you may try the following:

```php
foreach ($project->getTeams() as $key => $coordinator) { 
    $coordinatorImage = $teamImageUpload->uploadTeamImage(
            $form->get('teams')[$key]['cropped_file']->getData(), 
            $coordinator
    ); 
    $coordinator->setImage($coordinatorImage); 
}
```

This will allow you to run through your collection and see what they contain`.

Otherwise, you should consider using [Embedded collection of Forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) from Symfony docs.

Comment: I solved by doing             foreach ($project->getTeams() as $key => $coordinator) {
                $coordinatorImage = $teamImageUpload->uploadTeamImage($form->get('teams')[$key]['cropped_file']->getData(), $coordinator);
                $coordinator->setImage($coordinatorImage);
            } Please update it. I will accept.

Comment: Answer updated, glad you make it works !